# Is this the only way to reach Lake Lappajärvi with public transport?

Tags: public-transport, finland

This is my second question in a brief series on public transport in Finland.

After solving my [Inari/Ivalo conundrum](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/112526/26630), I plan to move south. After a stop in Rovaniemi, I plan to go towards Tampere, and possibly stopping at lake Lappajärvi along the way.

[It seems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rail_transport_in_Finland#/media/File:Finnish_railroad_network-en.svg) that I could get to Seinäjoki with the train, and then hop on a bus (with only one ride a day at 6 in the morning). Is this the only option?

Comment: Maybe ask a question on cheap car rental deals instead? I can't imagine traveling in that region without a car...

Comment: @JonathanReez again, no thanks, that's not an option :D I please ask everyone to stop suggesting cars.

Comment: Thing is it might even be cheaper than public transport if you travel with other people. Just give it a thought.

Comment: I have given it, and there are very good reasons for me not taking a car. If you are suggesting car hailing/sharing is a different thing, and you can list it in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Kauhava with train and with bus from Kauhava to Lappajärvi.

Comment: Do you have any details on which bus it is, where to take it from, when it leaves? The more information the better. :)

Comment: https://liput.matkahuolto.fi/connectionlist?lang=en&arrivalPlaceId=s5655&departurePlaceId=s3405&departureDate=2018-04-13  Matkahuolto (matkahuolto.fi/en) try that.

Comment: could you please add all these details to your answer?